# How do I modify symbols properly in plot_ly?

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I have a pca matrix with PCAtools that I am trying to plot in plot_ly. However whenever I specify symbols within the markers argument, the points disappear from the plot. When I specify the symbol outside the marker argument, the colorbar gets messed up.

This is the plot where the symbols are missing.

```
mtcars <- mtcars %>% mutate(make = substr(word(rownames(mtcars), 1), 1, 1), model = word(rownames(mtcars), 2))
pca <- PCAtools::pca(t(mtcars[,c(1:4)]), metadata = mtcars[,c("carb","gear","qsec", "make", "model")])
p <- plot_ly(data = pca$rotated, 
             x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, z = ~PC3,
             height = 600,
             marker = list(color = pca$metadata$qsec,
                           symbol = pca$metadata$make,
                           colorscale = "Jet",
                           colorbar = list(title = "Test")))
             
p
```

[image]

This is the plot where the color bar is messed up.

```
p <- plot_ly(data = pca$rotated, 
             x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, z = ~PC3,
             height = 600,
             marker = list(color = pca$metadata$qsec,
                           colorscale = "Jet",
                           colorbar = list(title = "Test",
                                           y = 0.5, x = 0)),
             symbol = pca$metadata$make)

p
```

[image]

Update:

```
p <- plot_ly(data = pca$rotated, 
             x = ~PC1, y = ~PC2, z = ~PC3,
             height = 600,
             marker = list(color = pca$metadata$qsec,
                           colorscale = "Jet",
                           colorbar = list(title = "Test",
                                           y = 0.5, x = 0, len = 0.5)),
             symbols = pca$metadata$make)
```

[image]

Comment: In your second plot, change `symbol` to `symbols`. If you want the colorbar to start at `y = .5`, you have to change the `len` (length) from the default of 1 (which is the entire height of the plot). `len = .5` in the call for the `colorbar` should work for you. :)

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and updated the post.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for at this point. I'm assuming something else isn't as you're expecting. If it has something to do with having alternative symbols, in 3d, there are only 6. If your choice for `symbol` has more than 6 discrete options, it won't work. Is that what you're looking for?